# Add a parent object to a created object in VFP

Tags: oop, object, foxpro

I have an object created with CREATEOBJECT() and I want to set him a parent object.
From msdn : 
`When you create an object with the CREATEOBJECT( ) function, the object is scoped to a property of the class or a variable in the method that calls this function. The parent property of the object is undefined.`

With .addobject() it's impossible because this method creates object , but I have already a created object .

The question is : how can I create  many objects (commandbuttons for example) which will have parent objects ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you want to add objects to an existing object? This is what the AddObject() function is used for. For example, you could create a container object, like a form, and then  myFormObject.AddObject("MyButton1", "CommandButton"). This will add a button to the form object. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: AddObject require the object class   (commandbutton in your example). But I have already a reference to a created object (for example : btn = createobject('commandbutton') . btn doesn't have a parent object). How can I "append" a parent object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an existing object and get a parent/child relationship. You can add an object reference to the existing object and while doing so, set a pseudo-parent. However, that won't give you a visible presence. That is, it's great for objects that are doing processing, but not for controls.

So why do you have a button that isn't already inside a container or on a form? It seems to me that there's a fundamental misunderstanding here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . I try to create some containers and return from method the array containing the container objects reference : `function createContainers lparameters a Do While (a != 0 )
This.containers(Alen(This.containers,1)) = CREATEOBJECT("container") 
Dimension This.containers( Alen(This.containers,1) + 1 )
a = a - 1
Enddo return this.containers endfunc ` There is another solution using macros subtition : `s = s+str(a) oPageFrame.pages(1).addobject("&s","container") ` , but I don't think this is an elegant solution.

Comment: Tamar , can you help me , please ?

Comment: Pass the form you want to put the containers in as a parameter to your function and then use AddObject() to create them.